# how can I read only one value of my dictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I created my own dictionary by taking the values ​​from a json file in the dictionary I have a set of values​​, the other can take them and use them, instead of these start with a brace can not seem to get them:

```
weather =     (
                {
            description = "broken clouds";
            icon = 04d;
            id = 803;
            main = Clouds;
        }
    );
```

Use this command to take the values ​​in the Dictionary:

```
NSString *currweather = myDict[@"weather"][@"main"];
```

The application quits when the launch. How can I fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *currweather = myDict[@"weather"][0][@"main"];
```

The `weather` key is referencing an array of dictionary.

You should have been given a clue from the error message about an unrecognized selector (`objectForKey:`) being called on an array class.